# Does ... mean all files in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Does ... mean all files in perforce?
....jpg means all jpg files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some examples from the [documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.fspecs.html):

> ... Matches all files under the
>   current working directory and all
>   subdirectories. (matches anything,
>   including slashes, and does so across
>   subdirectories)
>
> ./....c All files under the current
>   directory and its subdirectories, that
>   end in .c

Comment: It's not clear from Perforce's description there but I just wanted to add that `...` points to all files of which Perforce has knowledge, i.e. files in the depot and files submitted for add. It will ignore files not part of Perforce.

Answer (score 2):

... is essentially a full wildcard character so ...jpg is the equivalent of searching for *jpg in windows etc.

Its actually meaning depends on where is is used.  If used in search it will find all jpg files.  If used to define  a workspace

```
//depot/...  //myworkspace/...
```

This means that all files under depot should be put on the path defined by myworkspace.  But the meaning 'all' is the same.

Comment: note that ...jpg will match something like //depot/myfile.jpg as well as a file called //depot/myfile.this_is_a_jpeg.  ....jpg will return only files that have _only_ .jpg as the extension.  It's a subtle but important difference.